# Npm install of aurelia project in docker container gets stuck/hangs on jenkins build server

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, build, build-server

## Problem

Most of my Jenkins builds get stuck at `npm install`. The issue is not reproducible locally what makes it hard to narrow down. **The build server would just endlessly hang at a "random" package while until you'd manually stop it.**

```
16:33:55  [0m[91mnpm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-6.2.1.tgz 737ms
```

## Analysis

The frontend is developed with Aurelia and is part of a monorepo that is managed by Docker. This is my only project that uses Aurelia CLI so I thought I could find the problem there - but without any results.

I've already tried to analyze the issue by executing `npm install --verbose` but didn't gain any additional valuable information. It wasn't a specific package that lead to the problem nor was it a noticeable timeout.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:12.13.0 as builder
WORKDIR /web
COPY web .
RUN pwd
RUN npm install --verbose
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
COPY --from=builder /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index2.html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the problem for a long time, I discovered the newly introduced [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html) command and used it instead of [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) which solved the problem. Unfortunately installing a project with a clean state is a good idea ;-)

> This command is similar to npm-install, except it’s meant to be used
> in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous
> integration, and deployment – or any situation where you want to make
> sure you’re doing a clean install of your dependencies. It can be
> significantly faster than a regular npm install by skipping certain
> user-oriented features. It is also more strict than a regular install,
> which can help catch errors or inconsistencies caused by the
> incrementally-installed local environments of most npm users.